# To call a method in usercontrol from another user control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In the below code I have 2 user controls `sample.ascx` and `sample1.ascx` .I have a button in `sample.ascx` when I click the button it should call the method in `sample1.ascx`. Pls help me to do this.

**Sample.ascx**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="gmas" TagName="FieldCont" Src="~/Controls/Sample1.ascx" %>
<asp:Button id="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Save_Click"  />
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

**Sample1.ascx**

```
public bool IsValid()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         Sample1 ctrlB = new Sample1();

            ctrlB.IsValid();
      }
```

Comment: It throws error The type or namespace name sample1 could not be found

Comment: sample1 means your second user control class name may be it would be Sample1 or something @user3492682

Comment: Can u please tell me how to call page load method in sample1.ascx from sample.ascx

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1840288.aspx?How+To+call+the+one+user+control+Page+Load+Event+in+Another+Usercontrol+on+button+click+ @user3492682

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your user control code behind is Sample1 as mentioned below :

`public partial class Sample1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl`

and you can call **IsValid** method in button click event as mentioned below :

```
var control = new Sample1();
var isvalid = control.IsValid();
```

**Note:**

- IsValid method inside **Sample1.ascx.cs** should be **public**
- Namespace of 'Sample1' should be same as 'Sample'. If both are having different namespace then namespace of 'Sample1' should be included in 'Sample' by **`using`** directive

Comment: Can u please tell me how to call page load method in sample1.ascx from sample.ascx

Comment: include sample1.ascx in sample.ascx. it will call page_load by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be simple can u try with is code.

```
(new sample1()).<functionTocall>
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how to call page load method in sample1.ascx from sample.ascx on button click